# To detect lines in binary noisy image in python

Tags: python, opencv

I want to detect lines in binary image where some area having visible and some lines are near by
[image]

I need all the crosses,box and lines with gaps to in this image. I used `houghlinesp` opencv python, but not giving exact output.

Is there any other way to detect all lines in images?

Comment: Do you also wanna detect the dashed lines ? What do you mean by saying all the lines ?

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk yes

Answer (score 0):

HoughLinesP is Probabilistic

HoughLines use all dot
try using this

https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html

Comment: I tried this but this coding detects only horizontal and vertical lines